# How can I display the calendar based on choosing from date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I used http://www.daterangepicker.com/ to show calendar. And changed the style from left and right calendars to up and down calendars(calendars will be shown one by one). When I open the calendar, I want to show the calendar with from date in my calendar dropdown. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can show selected date in **Date Range picker**. For more [info](http://www.daterangepicker.com/).

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />    
    
    
    <input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
        opens: 'left'
      }, function(start, end, label) {
        console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
      });
    });
    </script>
```